# Spring Rest method always returning 405 Method not Allowed

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I am always getting 405 Method not allowed for a simple GET method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/servicetest")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public String checkService() {
    return "Service is up and running";
}
```

and WEb.xml is like

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">    

    <display-name>Interface</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:/application-root-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

     <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test-if</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test-if</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/testif/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am always getting 405 error when i am invoking the service.

Could you please let me know what am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace . that would be more helpful to deal with errors

Comment: You can only do a GET to the "testif/servicetest" url. Seems like you are trying to do a POST or any other Request Method type.

Comment: No, I am doing a get request http://localhost:8081/....../servicetest

Answer (score 1):

You have to use method type. Use that in your request mapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/servicetest", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
```

Comment: not really true, the default mapping for RequestMapping is GET, so its OK to omit it

Answer (score 1):

you have follow some steps.

1. if you using Spring Java Based configuration then add CORSFilter

   ```
   public class CORSFilter implements Filter {
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
       FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
   System.out
           .println("Filtering on...........................................................");
   HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
   response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
           "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
   response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
   response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
           "x-requested-with, Content-Type");
   chain.doFilter(req, res);
   }

   public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
   }

   public void destroy() {
   }
   }
   ```

OR

1. you are using xml based spring configuration then try to add

`<context:annotation-config/>` 
in your Spring configuration file. It will support your controller annotations.

2. configure @RequestMapping like below example

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/servicetest", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
   ```
3. still not working ?, then remove header from http call, just make simple http call, if this step not working then you can go for next step.
4. still not working then don't try to return actual entity just return proxy object or dummy object, if its working then go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<context:annotation-config/>` in your Spring configuration file. It will support your controller annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Do you send any additional parameters to the method. Seems like your method parameters don't match
Also I am thinking if you don't use @RestController annotation(you used here Responsebody) you should output/return your string/result as json.